# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null**, on ->

my html is to pass the value from function goSubmit(),

```
<form class="form-inline" id="formdaily" action="http://localhost:8080/reports/storewisedaily" method="POST">
          <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">Total Paid Orders - Report Data</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <table id="datatables" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Month - Year</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-01" onclick="goSubmit('2019-01')" href="#">2019-01</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-02" onclick="goSubmit('2019-02')" href="#">2019-02</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-03" onclick="goSubmit('2019-03')" href="#">2019-03</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-04" onclick="goSubmit('2019-04')" href="#">2019-04</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-05" onclick="goSubmit('2019-05')" href="#">2019-05</a></td>
                      <td>11,471.50</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-06" onclick="goSubmit('2019-06')" href="#">2019-06</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-07" onclick="goSubmit('2019-07')" href="#">2019-07</a></td>
                      <td>12.50</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-08" onclick="goSubmit('2019-08')" href="#">2019-08</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-09" onclick="goSubmit('2019-09')" href="#">2019-09</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-10" onclick="goSubmit('2019-10')" href="#">2019-10</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-11" onclick="goSubmit('2019-11')" href="#">2019-11</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                      <tr>
                      <td><a id="month_year" data-id="2019-12" onclick="goSubmit('2019-12')" href="#">2019-12</a></td>
                      <td>0.00</td>
                    </tr>
                                    <input type="hidden" id="select_month" name="select_month" value="">
                  <input type="hidden" id="select_store" name="select_store" value="3">
                </tbody>
                <tfoot align="right">
                  <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.box -->
          </form>
```

and in the function I want to pass the value of goSubmit() to the input hidden named "select_month"

```
  document.getElementById('select_month').value = m;
```

Even if I hard code the value, it seems not passing it. Can someone help my Friday and Saturday

```
<input type="hidden" id="select_month" name="select_month" value="">

function goSubmit(month_year) {
        alert(month_year); // it pass value '2019-05'
        var m = month_year.toString();
        console.log(m);
        alert(m);
        //alert($('#select_month').val(m));
        document.getElementById('select_month').value = m;
        //alert(document.getElementById("select_month").value);
        //alert($('#select_month').val(month_year));
        //$("#select_store").val(3);
        document.getElementById('select_store').value = 3;
        document.getElementById('formdaily').submit();
      }
```

Comment: Please update the question with relevant HTML....

Comment: why can't you access select_month hidden element directly? `document.getElementById('select_month')`

Comment: updated question with relevant html. @Mamun

Comment: Running your code I can not see any error!!! Also the the data are passed to the function which I can see in *alert* and *console*!!! Though your code could be improved.....

Answer (score 0):

#### Why your case is not working

it is because when your accessing your `elements` using `document.getElementById` it does not exists. you can do that may be after checking that DOM is ready or something like that.

There are other ways which will work without all that.

```
document.getElementById("formdaily").children.namedItem("select_month").value = "1234"
```

**note:** in upper case your `select_month` element must be a direct child of `formdaily`.

### Other Ways

#### By Name

```
document.getElementsByName("select_month")[0].value = 123;
```

#### By Query selector

```
document.querySelector("#formdaily input[name=select_month]").value = 5
```

#### By form element

```
document.forms.formdaily.select_month.value = 5
```

Comment: can you add your DOM hirarchy from `#formdaily ` to `select_month `

Comment: understood, your input element is deeply nested , thats why you can not access it `children.namedItem` this way, there is another way , let me update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Value is a property that exists on input tags, so give this try.
`document.getElementById("select_month").value = m`

Comment: In console you can print document.getElementById("select_month"). You will get some idea that whether you are able to properly fetch this id or not. Later you can see if its proving value property or not. You need to play with this code to achieve your target.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found out the error. It seems that javascript **cannot pass the value** to a *hidden input*. The solutions is I changed the input hidden to input type, then onload i will hide the input type for select_month. Now it will pass the value to the input text.